# What is the meaning of "subcortical retraction" in a description of MRI of a Kearns-Sayre syndrome patient?

Tags: terminology, brain, neurology, mri, white-matter

I came across the term **subcortical retraction** and cannot understand its meaning. Does it mean "the withering of the subcortical areas" (shrinking of subcortical white matter)?

From *[Follow-up of folinic acid supplementation for patients with cerebral folate deficiency and Kearns-Sayre syndrome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4302586/)*:

> Case 2. Multi Vane T2-Weighted TSE (T2W-MV) disclosed hyperintensity in dorsal brain stem (A), globus pallidus atrophy (B), **subcortical retraction** and white matter hyperintensity (C).

[image]